# Reordering of saving payload using @Async in Spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have wrapped one of the functions using `@Async` in my Spring boot application, where I persist the payload in DB as follows:

```
  @Component
  class StudentService {

   @Async
   public void saveA(Student student) {
     try {
       studentRepository.save(student);
     } catch (Exception e) {
       log.error("Error occurred while saving", e);
     }
   }
 }
```

**This function is getting called from another resource bean in the application as follows:**

```
  @RestController
  @RequestMapping("/api")
  class StudentResource {
   @PostMapping("/student")
   public ResponseEntity<String> createStudent(Student student) String threatCanvasId) { 
    String studentId = studentService.save(student);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(studentId);
   }
  }
```

Say, I now try to save two `Student`s: `A` followed by `B` calling the resource endpoint. Is there any chance that `B` gets saved before `A`?

Comment: Yes it's very possible, spring will delegate the jobs to other threads and they will finish it independently. There is no telling who finishes first.

Comment: Think about the created `Threads` as cars, that both have to go somewhere, at the time  you tell them both to start, there is no telling who goes to his destination first. So it is possible that it happens.